Deployment to Vercel Failed due to f files Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'
Hello I am attempting to deploy my very first next.js project to Vercel but when I click deployment I get this error message:
[15:43:14.701] Running "vercel build"
[15:43:15.145] Vercel CLI 33.6.3

[15:43:30.876] ├─ [32m✔︎[39m 2 themes added[2m      https://daisyui.com/docs/themes[22m
[15:43:30.876] ╰─ [32m★[39m [0mStar daisyUI on GitHub[0m    [2mhttps://github.com/saadeghi/daisyui[22m
[15:43:30.877] 
[15:43:31.578] request to https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/inter/v13/UcC73FwrK3iLTeHuS_fvQtMwCp50KnMa0ZL7W0Q5n-wU.woff2 failed, reason: 
[15:43:31.578] 
[15:43:31.578] Retrying 1/3...
[15:43:38.695] 
[15:43:38.695]    [35mdaisyUI[39m [2m4.9.0[22m
[15:43:38.927] ├─ [32m✔︎[39m 2 themes added[2m      https://daisyui.com/docs/themes[22m
[15:43:38.928] ╰─ [32m❤︎[39m [0mSupport daisyUI project:[0m [2mhttps://opencollective.com/daisyui[22m
[15:43:38.928] 
[15:43:39.435] request to https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100..900&display=swap failed, reason: 
[15:43:39.436] 
[15:43:39.436] Retrying 1/3...
[15:43:39.436] request to https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100..900&display=swap failed, reason: 
[15:43:39.440] Retrying 1/3...
[15:43:45.050] Failed to compile.
[15:43:45.050] ./node_modules/mailgun-js/lib/request.js
[15:43:45.050] Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'
[15:43:45.061] > Build failed because of webpack errors
[15:43:45.076] Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
[15:43:45.370] 

I've already taken the following steps: Removed any and all Mailgun-related files/dependencies from my project. Ran npm install to ensure all dependencies are up to date. Despite these efforts, I continue to face the same 'fs' module error during deployment.
Here are some additional details about my setup: Next.js version: 14.1.4 Deployment platform: Vercel Node.js version: v21.6.2
I've researched extensively online and reviewed the Next.js and Vercel documentation, but I haven't found a solution that resolves this specific problem.
Could someone please assist me in understanding why this 'fs' module error persists despite removing Mailgun-related files/dependencies? Any insights, suggestions, or further troubleshooting steps would be highly appreciated.
Thank you for your help!

Try adding { preload: true } to your font it seems like it's not able to fetch it properly.
